# How to generate ionic apk or ios without extra applications?

Tags: ios, build, ionic2, apk

Is there any ways to generate apk or ios file with using only node.js ?

most of solutions doesn't work or need some addition applications to build the application as apk/ios.

Comment: @the4kman yes. I searched for way to post it but I didn't know how

Comment: Post it under an appropriate question as an answer or ask your own question and answer it.

Comment: @the4kman ok I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of generating our application as "apk" or "ios" are so easy and fast and first of all open cmd screen with path of your application by using "shift + right click" on any place of your app folder > "open command windows here" and follow the steps

---

**For APK, enter:**

```
ionic package build android
```

**For IOS, enter:**

```
ionic package build ios
```

*This process will take few minutes (just wait until the end)*

**Next step** To download our apk/ios file, just enter:

```
ionic package download
```

*when downloading completed, you will find the apk/ios file in the same path of your application*

> **Very important note:** sometime downloading process will display error message such as "your application not ready to download".
>
> **The solution very simple**, just try to wait one or two minutes and re-write downloading command.

---

*Finally, These commands tested on Ionic 2 so I'm not sure if its works with other Ionic versions.*