# White screen after splash screen in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2, wait, splash-screen

I have small problem with white screen after execute splash screen when I convert my application to *.apk, Its take 20 to 25 seconds then my application run fine.

So is there any settings or codes or any tools that solves this problem?

**Notes**

> ~ Application size : 19mb
>
> ~ Tested on Samsung galaxy J7 2016 - android 7.0
>
> ~ I used this way to convert my app to apk : [How to generate ionic apk or ios without extra applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46040847/6152553)

Answer (score 2):

by using

> ionic build android --prod

The boot time will reduced to like 5 seconds and for the white screen,

the issue was Splash screen autohiding, so disable the splash screen auto hide and from

> app.component.ts

i hid it manually.

> config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000"/>
 <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
 <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
 <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
@Component({
 templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
 rootPage:string = 'HomePage';
 constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
 platform.ready().then(() => {
 // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
 // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
 statusBar.styleDefault();
 splashScreen.hide();
 });
 }
}
```

Comment: So can I understand 20 second of wait before start my app is normal thing for all applications that developed by ionic ? Because I used every thing to solve this problem but nothing allow me to lunch my application without waiting less than 20 seconds

Comment: Use the production build , It make the Boot time faster 
ionic build android --prod

Answer (score 1):

To build your apk file just use:

```
ionic build android 
(or) ionic cordova build android (In ionic3)
```

To run your app in device just use:

```
ionic run android (ionic cordova run android)
(or) ionic run android --livereload (for live reload) (ionic cordova run android --livereload)
```

See more about [ioni cli](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/)
20s launch app is **normal** with debug mode. Run `ionic build` with `--prod` varible, you will see your app launch much faster but it take more time to build.

Comment: So can I understand 20 second of wait before start my app is normal thing for all applications that developed by ionic ? Because I used every thing to solve this problem but nothing allow me to lunch my application without waiting less than 20 seconds

Comment: Anther point, I checked your commands but its show me errors.. may be I should install some adds like android studio or something else

Comment: Yes. It is normal for all app. See this [guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/) to build your app